# angular2 trying to host a cli project in a non root dir

Tags: angular

I am trying to publish the project to a node server which resides in a path that is non root.
this is the project: https://github.com/splintercode/ng-pokedex

In other words:
https://secure.digitalsignage.com/poke/ (poke dir)
as you cam see, I get no assets
I did publish with:

```
ng build --target=production --base-href ./
ng build --target=production --base-href /poke
ng build --target=production --base-href /poke/
ng build --target=production --base-href ./poke
```

with no luck
and you can clearly see the error in dev tools.

I was wondering if anyone has an idea on how to host in a non root node server dir.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
<head>
  <base href="/poke">
```

or

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/poke'}, ...],
  ...
})
export class AppModule() {}
```

Comment: I did try every possible combination on  <base href="/poke"> but will give the providers a shot as well now... tx!!!!

Comment: by the way you can clearly see that it is able to load the app just fine, but not able to load the: https://secure.digitalsignage.com/manifest.json Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), so I am not sure why it is trying the manifest from the root?

Comment: `<base href="...">` has influence to other directives in `<head>` and might break imports or similar, `APP_BASE_HREF` only configures the router.

Comment: Perhaps your server doesn't support HTML5 pushState? I don't know Node.js.

Comment: tried that APP_BASE and same :( while I dont know the answer, I am sure somewhere I need to configure the proper path to the manifest file... just can't find location :/

Comment: Sorry, don't know about manifest file either. base href and server not supporting (or not being configured to support) HTML5 pushState are usually the cause for 404

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issues by changing paths manually inside service-worker.js